The Azure Virtual Machine hostname does not change in terraform
We use custom images to deploy virtual machines in Terraform. Custom images have our standardized settings. However, if you use this custom image to deploy it in Terraform, your hostname will not change and it will unconditionally appear as "rockylinuximage01".
Our code is as below.

var.tf

variable "vm_template" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    vm1 = {
      source_image_id = "/subscriptions/00000/resourceGroups/image/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/new-image-rocky8"
      vm_name         = "test-vm"
      hostname        = "test-vm"
      os_publisher    = "resf"
      os_offer        = "rockylinux-x86_64"
      os_sku          = "8-base"
      os_version      = "8.9.20231119"
      osdisk_type     = "StandardSSD_LRS"
      osdisk_size     = "32"
      vm_type         = "Standard_D2s_v5"
      nic             = "nic01"
      os_disk         = "osdisk01"
    }
  }
}


vm.tf

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                = var.kv_name
  resource_group_name = var.kv_rg
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "password" {
  name         = var.kv_secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "system_rg_name" {
  name = var.system_rg
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "network_subnet" {
  name                 = var.network_subnet
  virtual_network_name = var.network_vnet
  resource_group_name  = var.network_rg
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  for_each                      = var.vm_template
  name                          = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.nic}"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  enable_accelerated_networking = true
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.network_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.private-ip-type
    private_ip_address            = each.value.private_ip
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each = var.vm_template
  name                = each.value.vm_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  source_image_id     = each.value.source_image_id
  zone                = each.value.zone
  #### VM Instance Type
  size = each.value.vm_type

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id,
  ]

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.os_disk}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite" # ReadOnly, ReadWrite
    storage_account_type = each.value.osdisk_type
    disk_size_gb         = each.value.osdisk_size
  }

  plan {
    name      = each.value.os_sku
    publisher = each.value.os_publisher
    product   = each.value.os_offer
  }

  computer_name  = each.value.hostname
  admin_username = var.adminid
  admin_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.password.value
 
  disable_password_authentication = false

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      admin_password,
    ]
  }
}

If you create and distribute the code using the custom image as above, the "test-vm" you set in "computer_name" will be changed to "rockylinuximage01". I want the hostname I set to be applied to the server. Please help.

Apparently both the name and hostname properties are set with the right values for the vm1. Is this the only VM you're trying to create? Can you please show the generated plan?

If the hostname changes to the default name rockylinuximage01, you can change the name, using the hostnamectl set-hostname test-vm command. Run that script on the VM once it is created using a null_resource block in Terraform

Assuming you use "null_resource" or "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension", what if there are multiple vms to create?


The Azure Virtual Machine hostname does not change in terraform

I have created a Rocky Linux VM using a custom image, and it's taking the specified computer_name from the Terraform code.
In your case, it's taking another computer name, which may indicate that it's not using the current Terraform configuration. Please verify the plan before applying it, and also delete any previously created state files before running the code again.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "RG-Name"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "rockyvnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
lifecycle  {
    prevent_destroy = true
    }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "rocky-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
lifecycle  {
    prevent_destroy = true
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "rockyvm-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
lifecycle  {
    prevent_destroy = true
    }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "Linuxvm-Rocky"
  source_image_id     = "/subscriptions/11111b-b5ba-21111111/resourceGroups/RG-name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/Venkatgallery/images/Venkat-Image"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_D2s_v5"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  computer_name      = "Rockylinuxvm"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "Welcome@123$"
  disable_password_authentication = false

  os_disk {
    name                 = "rockyosdisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = "128"
  }



  plan {
    name      = "8-base"
    publisher = "resf"
    product   = "rockylinux-x86_64"
  }
  lifecycle  {
    prevent_destroy = true
    }
}


Terraform Apply

VM Hostname

If it is still taking the default name, you can change the hostname using the command sudo hostnamectl set-hostname Linux-RockyVM with a VM extension.
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "commandToExecute": "sudo hostnamectl set-hostname Linux-RockyVM && sudo systemctl restart"
 }
SETTINGS
}

After executing the VM Extension, the hostname was changed successfully.

Reference: azurerm_virtual_machine_extension

Assuming you use "null_resource" or "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension", what if there are multiple vms to create?

To apply azurerm_virtual_machine_extension to multiple VMs in Terraform, you can use  for-each loop in extension block .

sudo hostnamectl set-hostname Linux-RockyVM && sudo systemctl restart I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how to implement this part as for_ech. Isn't this a shell script? How can I change the hostname of multiple VMs in this part? I'm not sure.

Thank you to everyone who helped. I'd like to put my opinions together and use the code modified as follows. I don't know if this is a better way or not, but I'm sure it meets the requirements anyway. Below is the modified code. If you have any better opinions, I would greatly appreciate it if you could let me know.
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "run_command" {
  for_each             = var.vm_template
  name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-run_command"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm[each.key].id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"
  timeouts {
    create = "1h"
  }
  settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "commandToExecute": "bash -c 'hostnamectl set-hostname --static ${each.value.hostname}'"
 }
SETTINGS
}

